# Sorting selected questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, sorting

How do I get ["unanswered/my tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags) questions sorted by *date*, not by *votes*, like ["questions/newest"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)?

If this is not possible now, please consider this as a feature request:

- make it possible to **sort** and **filter** questions *independently*, e.g., *select* questions for tags (inclusive/exclusive) and then *sort* them by views/votes/bounty/time/author's reputation &c.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+%5Bfoo%5D+is%3Aquestion).  You'll need to enter the tags explicitly, but other than that you can sort on date and filter out questions with answers, or with an accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for the link. how do I search for _either_ `[r]` _or_ `[lisp]`?

Comment: Currently you cannot.